# I want to open a specific folder on file upload button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a folder on client side and now i want whenever the user uses file upload functionality that folder is opened in file open dialog by default.
I have to use front-end scripting language only like javascript/ JQuery.

Comment: And what is your specific question ?

Comment: impossible. you need to write your own browser...

Comment: You possibly cant do that.. the OS takes care of which directory is shown in the dialog box by default...

Comment: @Jonasw not a temporary fix like that.  need a permanent solution :D

Comment: I am not sure how you `created a folder on client side`

Comment: This code is needed for the browser extension we created. as it add to browser a new folder gets created. The real moto is to set the value to file up loader from that folder

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use only `chrome.downloads.showDefaultFolder()`

Comment: thanks @anete.anetes. but this is the default functionality that the browser's default folder gets open in file open. now the thing is i have to set my folder as a default folder for browser

Comment: It's not achivable by security reasons. I have some plugins which needed this functionality, but still have no chance to achive that.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do this. I also didn't get anything .